# How can I pre-process .rb files in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, preprocessor, customization, asset-pipeline

I wrote a Ruby language pre-processor that I also want to tie in to Rails.

Accomplishing this isn't exactly clear from my research.  I want the same effect of having .rb.erb or .rb.haml but on files that are not templates(models and controllers, for example). It seems that typical pre-processing is specific to the asset pipeline.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing

Does anyone know where I could start in writing a pre-processor for code that is **not** part of the asset pipeline?

**EDIT:** I want to do something to the following effect:

- Write Ruby code in a custom syntax.
- Each file with the custom syntax has an extra extension to denote custom syntax. For example, the model page.rb would be page.rb.custom.
- When Rails runs(or when Spring reloads the app), code that has a .custom file extension is preprocessed(or precompiled, rather) into pure Ruby and is executed.

Comment: This seems quite bizarre to me.  Ruby is already syntactically brilliant, what are you attempting to do by pre-processing it o.O

Comment: I would start looking at same gems to see how they incorporate their preprocessors into the Rails app, than create a gem with your code and bam. That is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Remember: "Just because you can doesn't mean you should." If you're curious, though, look at how `ERB` itself is implemented as a handler within Rails.

Comment: Other gems use the asset pipeline.  I can't use the asset pipeline if I'm not pre-processing assets.(edit: as far as I can tell)

Comment: No, seriously, what do you want to achieve? You want to make `require` parse/preprocess files and only them execute them?

Comment: I want to do something to the following effect:

- Write Ruby code in a slightly custom syntax.  
- Each file with the custom syntax has an extra extension to denote custom syntax.  For example, the model page.rb would be page.rb.custom.
- When Rails runs, code that has a .custom file extension is preprocessed(or precompiled, rather) into traditional Ruby and is executed.